# Erro Sequence contains no elements asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootgrid

Bom dia.

Eu estou tentando enviar uma requisição em ajax no jquery, mas ele me retorna esse erro. Sequence contains no elements, eu estou querendo apresentar dados no bootgrid

```
public ParametrosPaginacao(NameValueCollection dados)
        {

            string chave = dados.AllKeys.Where(k => k.StartsWith("asc")).First();

            string ordenacao = dados[chave];
            string campo = chave.Replace("sort[", String.Empty).Replace("]", String.Empty);

            CampoOrdenado = String.Format("{0} {1}", campo, ordenacao);

            Current = int.Parse(dados["current"]);
            RowCount = int.Parse(dados["RowCount"]);
            SearchPhrase = dados["searchPhrase"];

        }

        public int Current { get; set; }
        public int RowCount { get; set; }
        public string SearchPhrase { get; set; }
        public string CampoOrdenado { get; set; }

}
```

Meu ajax

```
$(document).on('click', '#contratos_vigentes', function () {

    var Status = $('#Status option:selected').text();
    var Gestor_Acc = $('#Gestor_Acc option:selected').text();
    var Gestor_Retida = $('#Gestor_Retida option:selected').text();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'FiltrarEPaginar',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { status : Status, gestor_acc : Gestor_Acc, gestor_Retida : Gestor_Retida },

    });
    //window.location.href = "Contratos_Vigentes?status=" + Status + "&gestor_acc=" + Gestor_Acc + "&gestor_retida=" + Gestor_Retida;

});
```

Meu controller

```
public JsonResult Contratos_Vigentes(ParametrosPaginacao parametrosPaginacao, string status, string gestor_acc, string gestor_retida)
        {
            DadosFiltrados dadosFiltrados = FiltrarEPaginar(parametrosPaginacao,  status, gestor_acc,  gestor_retida);

            return Json(dadosFiltrados, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public DadosFiltrados FiltrarEPaginar(ParametrosPaginacao parametrosPaginacao, string status, string gestor_acc, string gestor_retida)
        {

            var areaVigentes = db.Contratos.Count();
            int total = 0;
            string[] usuario_perfil = User_Role();
            ViewBag.status = status;
            ViewBag.gestor_acc = gestor_acc;
            ViewBag.gestor_retida = gestor_retida;
            List<Contrato> contrato_saldo_Vigencia1 = new List<Contrato>();

            if (usuario_perfil[1] == "Administrador" || usuario_perfil[1] == "Accenture")
            {
                //Efetua busca com base nos filtros inseridos pelo usuário e retorna quantitativo de contratos com status Vigente
                contrato_saldo_Vigencia1 = db.Contratos.Where(a => a.DescStatusVigente == "Vigente").ToList();
            }
            else if (usuario_perfil[1] == "Accenture_Saldo_Vigencia")
            {
                contrato_saldo_Vigencia1 = db.Contratos.Where(a => a.DescStatusVigente == "Vigente" && a.EmailGestor == usuario_perfil[0]).ToList();
            }

            if (status != "" && status != null)
            {
                contrato_saldo_Vigencia1 = contrato_saldo_Vigencia1.Where(j => j.DescAreaCliente.Contains(status)).ToList();
            }
            if (gestor_acc != "" && gestor_acc != null)
            {
                contrato_saldo_Vigencia1 = contrato_saldo_Vigencia1.Where(j => j.DescGestorAcc == gestor_acc).ToList();
            }
            if (gestor_retida != "" && gestor_retida != null)
            {
                contrato_saldo_Vigencia1 = contrato_saldo_Vigencia1.Where(j => j.DescGestorRetida == gestor_retida).ToList();
            }
            var AreasAccenturePaginados = contrato_saldo_Vigencia1.OrderBy(parametrosPaginacao.CampoOrdenado).Skip((parametrosPaginacao.Current - 1) * parametrosPaginacao.RowCount).Take(parametrosPaginacao.RowCount);

            DadosFiltrados dadosFiltrados = new DadosFiltrados(parametrosPaginacao)
            {
                rows = AreasAccenturePaginados.ToList(),
                total = total
            };


            return dadosFiltrados;


        }
```

Segue stacktrace

```
[InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements]
   System.Linq.Enumerable.First(IEnumerable`1 source) +403
   PortalAdmCC.ViewModels.ParametrosPaginacao..ctor(NameValueCollection dados) in C:\Users\gabriel.da.c.falieri\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PACO\PortalAdmCC\PortalAdmCC\ViewModels\ParametrosPaginacao.cs:14
   PortalAdmCC.Infra.ParametrosPaginacaoModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) in C:\Users\gabriel.da.c.falieri\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PACO\PortalAdmCC\PortalAdmCC\Infra\ParametrosPaginacaoModelBinder.cs:16
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +331
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +105
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +743
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +465
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__14(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +18
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +374
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +384
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +443
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +132
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163
```

Comment: Poderia incluir o stacktrace do erro?

Comment: Claro  @lgomide, coloquei o stacktrace

Comment: Se poder dar uma olhada por favor

Comment: Verifique o complemento que coloquei (editei a resposta)

Comment: Sim, mas acontece que percebi uma coisa hoje, esse erro nao está acotecendo só com essa tela, até com outras que já estavam prontas

Answer (score 1):

O erro diz que você tentou extrair um elemento de uma sequência, mas ela não possuía nenhum. Provavelmente o erro vem desta linha (método **First()** )

```
string chave = dados.AllKeys.Where(k => k.StartsWith("asc")).First();
```

Portanto, é necessário que o seu código trate o caso em que não há chaves que comecem com "asc".

O seu código ajax não envia o parâmetro **parametrosPaginacao**, que deveria ser um objeto, para o controller. Por isso o framework ASP.NET MVC falha na execução do construtor. Há duas opções:

1 - Modificar o construtor para tratar o caso em que o parâmetro **dados** é nulo ou vazio.

2 - Modificar o javascript para montar e enviar o objeto Parametrospaginacao para o controller.

Comment: Sim, o erro vem dessa linha mesmo

Comment: <tr>
            <th data-column-id="Id" data-order="asc">Contrato</th>
            <th data-column-id="FornecedorNome">Fornecedor</th>
            <th data-column-id="DtCriacao">Data Inicio</th>
            <th data-column-id="DtFim">Data Fim</th>
            <th data-column-id="Gestor_Acc">Gestor Acc</th>
            <th data-formatter="Detalhes" data-sortable="false">Detalhes</th>
        </tr>

Tenho esse tr